# How to remove background gray drawings from image in OPENCV python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I need to remove the gray drawing from the image background and only need symbols drawn over it.

Here is my code to do that using morphologyEx but it did not remove the entire gray drawing that is in background.

```
img_path = "images/new_drawing.png"
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

kernel = np.ones((2,2), dtype=np.uint8)
result = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow('Without background',result);

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried this also and got expected results in grayscale but unable to convert it to BGR.

Here is my code

```
img = cv2.imread('images/new_drawing.png')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
med_blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray_img, ksize=3)

_, thresh = cv2.threshold(med_blur, 190, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
blending = cv2.addWeighted(gray_img, 0.5, thresh, 0.9, gamma=0)
cv2.imshow("blending", blending);
```

Also i used contours to identify symbols and draw them to white image but problem is that it also identify background drawing that i don't want.

Input image

[image]

Expected output image

[image]

Also the drawing will be always in gray color as in image.

Please help me out to get better result.

Comment: the lines you want to get rid of are medium brightness and low saturation while the stuff you are interested in is high sturation or (low saturation and low brightness). convert your image to HSB apply thresholds and combine them with logical operations. another more straight forward approach is to use template matching, in case you have known set of symbols. find their location and redraw the image with the found positions.

Comment: I tried this also --->                                                                                                        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV);                                          
lower_color = np.array([20, 30, 0])
upper_color = np.array([179, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_color, upper_color)                                           
new_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

Comment: In this approach, i get only colored symbols in mask but not alphabets in black color. It will be helpful if you could tell what operator should I use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there...

Instead of using `cv2.inRange` to "catch" the non-gray pixel I suggest using `cv2.inRange` for catching all the pixels you want to change to white color:

```
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 0, 100), (255, 5, 255))
```

- The hue range is irrelevant.
- The saturation is close to zero (shades of gray).
- The brightness excludes the black pixels (you like to keep).

In order to get a nicer solution, I also used the following additional stages:

- Build a mask of non-black pixels:

  ```
  nzmask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 0, 5), (255, 255, 255))
  ```
- Erode the above mask:

  ```
  nzmask = cv2.erode(nzmask, np.ones((3,3)))
  ```
- Apply `and` operation between `mask` and `nzmask`:

  ```
  mask = mask & nzmask
  ```

The above stages keeps the gray pixels around the black text.
Without the above stages, the black text gets thinner.

- The last stage is replacing `mask` pixels with white:

  ```
  new_img = img.copy()
  new_img[np.where(mask)] = 255
  ```

---

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img_path = "new_drawing.png"
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 0, 100), (255, 5, 255))
cv2.imshow('mask before and with nzmask', mask);

# Build mask of non black pixels.
nzmask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 0, 5), (255, 255, 255))

# Erode the mask - all pixels around a black pixels should not be masked.
nzmask = cv2.erode(nzmask, np.ones((3,3)))
cv2.imshow('nzmask', nzmask);

mask = mask & nzmask

new_img = img.copy()
new_img[np.where(mask)] = 255

cv2.imshow('mask', mask);
cv2.imshow('new_img', new_img);
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it worked perfectly. But a little thing that i noticed , when i convert input image to grayscale and apply this approach then the symbol in the left of letter E is also removed along with lines. I need that symbol also

Comment: The solution utilize the fact that the input is colored. That is the reason for converting to HSV color space, and using the saturation (`S` channel) when computing the `mask`. Convert the image to grayscale after applying the approach. In case the input is grayscale, a different approach is required.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to HSV and separate channels
- Threshold the saturation channel
- Threshold the value channel and invert
- Combine the two threshold images as a mask
- Apply the mask to the input to write white where the mask is black
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('symbols.png')

# convert image to hsv colorspace
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)

# threshold saturation image
thresh1 = cv2.threshold(s, 92, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# threshold value image and invert
thresh2 = cv2.threshold(v, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh2 = 255 - thresh2

# combine the two threshold images as a mask
mask = cv2.add(thresh1,thresh2)

# use mask to remove lines in background of input
result = img.copy()
result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)

# display IN and OUT images
cv2.imshow('IMAGE', img)
cv2.imshow('SAT', s)
cv2.imshow('VAL', v)
cv2.imshow('THRESH1', thresh1)
cv2.imshow('THRESH2', thresh2)
cv2.imshow('MASK', mask)
cv2.imshow('RESULT', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save output image
cv2.imwrite('symbols_thresh1.png', thresh1)
cv2.imwrite('symbols_thresh2.png', thresh2)
cv2.imwrite('symbols_mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('symbols_cleaned.png', result)
```

Saturation channel thresholded:

[image]

Value channel thresholded and inverted:

[image]

Mask:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your precious effort. It's working fine but while performing this code on a grayscale image of this colored image then some symbol(left of letter E) has disappeared also.

Comment: Adjust the threshold value on the value image and see if that does better.